# Changing your character name

Tags: diablo-iii

Let's say you create a Barbarian with the name Bill. Is it possible (at all) after you have been hacking and slashing for a while, to change Bill's name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

However, I think it's safe to assume that Blizzard will add this as a paid service at some point just like they did in WoW.